# gradle project sync failed. basic functionality

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have an error "gradle project sync failed. basic functionality" and my system file has been corrupt show in image below[image: All system files like builder.gradle, google-services.json etc are corrupted]

Comment: I guess there is some problem with your proguard file, could you delete it and resync it., just to check where the problem is?

Comment: no, i try your suggestion its same as it is, i am trying to download latest gradle file and use it..but you find something please let me know

Comment: Getting this error,14:41 Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
   build file 'D:\CRM\app\build.gradle': 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 5.
   ����   4     
   ^
   1 error
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2 m 54 s 822 ms)

Comment: I think you should have a look at your build.gradle. You could also add your build.gradle so that others can help you. With just the image it would be difficult.

Comment: I just deleted build file and clone from git. its help for me.

Comment: Great. Finally solved